# How to reference a custom class in Laravel 5.1?

Tags: laravel

I'm having trouble referencing my custom class to my `foldername/x.blade.php` page. I have my php class under `App\libs\` folder. I have tried to figure it out, but wasted alot of my time... any help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Go go /config/app.php and add it to aliases like this

```
'MyClass' => App\libs\MyClass::class,
```

Comment: you are too good.it just worked like charm..Thanks alot..@Bojan